# Порядок передачи аргументов с помощью метода apply

Tags: javascript

Есть функция `bind`, которая фиксирует контекст для func.

```
function bind(func, context) {
  return function() { // (*)
    return func.apply(context, arguments);
  };
}
```

Например, привяжем контекст для функции `f`.

```
function f() {
  alert( this );
}

var g = bind(f, "Context");
g(); // Context
```

Вопрос: почему аргументы на передачу в функцию надо записывать в `g(1, 2)`, а не в `bind(f, "Context", 1, 2)`? Правильно ли я понял, что `bind` возвращает в переменную `g` анонимную функцию и таким образом при вызове `g()` в эту функцию передаются аргументы?

Comment: можно и в `bind`

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bind#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос: почему аргументы на передачу в функцию надо записывать в g(1, 2), а не в bind(f, "Context", 1, 2)?

Потому что функция `bind` в текущем виде оперирует **только** с двумя первыми переданными аргументами.

Вызвать функций `bind` в виде `bind(f, "Context", 1, 2)` можно, но это никак не скажется на выполнении функции `g`.